# Bootstrap issue - overflow on the right

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am building a web app which is basically just one page containing a table.

The code looks more or less like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body style="width: 100%">

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xl-12">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top mb-3" style="height:10px" >
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="en">en</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="zh">中</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:70px;">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">

      <table class="table table-striped" style="width: 100%; font-size: 16px !important;">

          <thead>
              <tr>

                  <th class="text-center" scope="col">E.g.1</th>
                  <th class="text-center" scope="col">E.g.2</th>
                  <th class="text-center" scope="col">E.g.3</th>
                  <th class="text-center" scope="col">E.g.4</th>
                  <th class="text-center" scope="col">E.g.5</th>
                  <th class="text-center" scope="col">E.g.6</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
              <tr>
                    <td class="text-center">Text 1</td>
                    <td class="text-center">Text 2</td>
                    <td class="text-center">Text 3</td>
                    <td class="text-center">Text 4</td>
                    <td class="text-center">Text 5</td>
                    <td class="text-center">Text 6</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                    <td class="text-center">Text 1</td>
                    <td class="text-center">Text 2</td>
                    <td class="text-center">Text 3</td>
                    <td class="text-center">Text 4</td>
                    <td class="text-center">Text 5</td>
                    <td class="text-center">Text 6</td>
              </tr>

          </tbody>
      </table>

  </div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

So it should just displaying a navigation bar on top and then a table.

The problem is the following: while the page fits the screen good on laptop, it always overflows on the right (around 20% of the size) when opening the page from smartphone (then it is possible to "zoom out" and make the page occupy the full screen, but I want the table to fit the screen already when opening the page).

Also, note that if I replace:

```
      <table class="table table-striped"
```

with

```
      <table
```

The page fits the screen correctly from smartphone as well, but I want to be able to use the table-striped style.

EDIT:
The behaviour can be reproduced by copy-pasting the code here:
https://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer
Opening it from smartphone, you can see the last one and a half column overflows on the right, while this does not happen on laptop.

I'm quite sure I'm missing something basic here related to bootstrap, but I've been trying to change things for a few hours now with no results, so I hope someone can give me a hint on what could possibly go wrong here. Thank you!

Comment: That's strange, because the _table-striped_ class just adds color to the tr:nth-of-type, it has nothing to do with sizes or overflow.
Anyway, I cannot reproduce the error, it works fine with and without the table-strip class. Maybe there's another part in your code that's interfering with this behavior?

Comment: There's actually no other part of code..

Comment: I mean, just more columns (6 in total) and lines in the table and the data are obviously placeholders, but that's it. (perhaps with 6 columns instead of 3 the weird behaviour appears)

Comment: I've edited the original post, changing the table from 3 columns to 6 columns, now should be easier to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I still see no difference between striped and normal. I mean, they both overflow on smartphones (because of the font size that is forced to 16px). Unless you decrease that font-size, (or the number of columns) it will always overflow